# Use Pyspark df.select() to stack the output

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code:                                               .                                  .

```
base_curr = 'BTC,XRP,ETH'
uri = f"https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms={base_curr}&tsyms=JPY"
r = requests.get(uri)rdd = sc.parallelize([r.text])
json_df = sqlContext.read.json(rdd)
json_df = json_df.select(
    col('RAW.BTC.JPY.FROMSYMBOL').alias('FROMSYMBOL'),
    F.col('RAW.BTC.JPY.PRICE').alias('PRICE'),
    F.col('RAW.BTC.JPY.LASTUPDATE').alias('LASTUPDATE'),

    F.col('RAW.XRP.JPY.FROMSYMBOL').alias('FROMSYMBOL'),
    F.col('RAW.XRP.JPY.PRICE').alias('PRICE'),  
    F.col('RAW.XRP.JPY.LASTUPDATE').alias('LASTUPDATE'),
    
    F.col('RAW.ETH.JPY.FROMSYMBOL').alias('FROMSYMBOL'),
    F.col('RAW.ETH.JPY.PRICE').alias('PRICE'),
    F.col('RAW.ETH.JPY.LASTUPDATE').alias('LASTUPDATE')
)
print(json_df)
json_df.show()
json_df.printSchema()
```

The output is:

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----+----------+----------+--------+----------+
|FROMSYMBOL|     PRICE|LASTUPDATE|FROMSYMBOL|PRICE|LASTUPDATE|FROMSYMBOL|   PRICE|LASTUPDATE|
+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----+----------+----------+--------+----------+
|       BTC|1994390.75|1607158504|       XRP|61.85|1607158490|       ETH|61874.24|1607158509|
+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----+----------+----------+--------+----------+
```

But the desired output is:

```
+----------+----------+----------+
|FROMSYMBOL|     PRICE|LASTUPDATE|
+----------+----------+----------+
|       BTC|1994390.75|1607158504|
+----------+----------+----------+
|       XRP|61.85     |1607158490|  
+----------+----------+----------+
|       ETH|61874.24  |1607158509|
+----------+----------+----------+
```

Any help would be so great. I tried several method without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
base_curr = 'BTC,XRP,ETH'
uri = f"https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms={base_curr}&tsyms=JPY"
r = requests.get(uri)
rdd = sc.parallelize([r.text])
json_df = sqlContext.read.json(rdd)

json_df = json_df.select(
    F.explode(
        F.array(
            F.array(F.col('RAW.BTC.JPY.FROMSYMBOL').alias('FROMSYMBOL'),
                    F.col('RAW.BTC.JPY.PRICE').alias('PRICE'),
                    F.col('RAW.BTC.JPY.LASTUPDATE').alias('LASTUPDATE')
                   ),
    
            F.array(F.col('RAW.XRP.JPY.FROMSYMBOL').alias('FROMSYMBOL'),
                    F.col('RAW.XRP.JPY.PRICE').alias('PRICE'),  
                    F.col('RAW.XRP.JPY.LASTUPDATE').alias('LASTUPDATE')
                    ),
    
            F.array(F.col('RAW.ETH.JPY.FROMSYMBOL').alias('FROMSYMBOL'),
                    F.col('RAW.ETH.JPY.PRICE').alias('PRICE'),
                    F.col('RAW.ETH.JPY.LASTUPDATE').alias('LASTUPDATE')
                    )
        )
    ).alias('arrays')
).select(
    F.col('arrays')[0].alias('FROMSYMBOL'),
    F.col('arrays')[1].alias('PRICE'),
    F.col('arrays')[2].alias('LASTUPDATE'),
)
```

Comment: Thanks. It gives the error `Only one generator allowed per select clause but found 3`

Comment: Yes! It works but the parenthesis before the `.alias('arrays')` should not be there. It create an error. Thanks